# Oracle query to find all occurrences of a charcter in a string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to write an Oracle query in toad to find all the occurrences of a character in a string. For example if I'm searching for `R` in the string `SSSRNNSRSSR`, it should return positions 4, 8 and 11.

I am new to Oracle and tried this.

```
select instr(mtr_ctrl_flags, 'R', pos + 1, 1) as pos1 
  from mer_trans_reject  
 where pos in ( select instr(mtr_ctrl_flags, 'R', 1, 1) as pos 
                  from mer_trans_reject
                       );
```

where `mtr_ctrl_flags` is the column name. I'm getting an error indicating that `pos` is an invalid identifier.

Comment: Interesting challenge. This would become either a very odd query, or you'll have to write a stored procedure. Or there is is always that last, unfortunate possibility that there's some handy feature I don't know of...

Comment: A (self written) function might be more efficient than using any kind of recursive query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - It might be, but don't underestimate the overhead of calling functions. It would be an interesting test, though, but currently, I only have sqlfiddle, and I doubt if that's a reliable benchmarking platform.

Answer (score 16):

Extending GolezTrol's answer you can use regular expressions to significantly reduce the number of recursive queries you do:

```
 select instr('SSSRNNSRSSR','R', 1, level)
   from dual
connect by level <= regexp_count('SSSRNNSRSSR', 'R')
```

[REGEXP_COUNT()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions080.htm#SQLRF00651) returns the number of times the pattern matches, in this case the number of times `R` exists in `SSSRNNSRSSR`. This limits the level of recursion to the exact number you need to.

[INSTR()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions080.htm#SQLRF00651) simply searches for the index of R in your string. `level` is the depth of the recursion but in this case it's also the level *th* occurrence of the string as we restricted to the number of recurses required.

If the string you're wanting to pick out is more complicated you could go for regular expressions ans [REGEXP_INSTR()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions148.htm#SQLRF06300) as opposed to INSTR() but it will be slower (not by much) and it's unnecessary unless required.

---

Simple benchmark as requested:

The two CONNECT BY solutions would indicate that using REGEXP_COUNT is 20% quicker on a string of this size.

```
SQL> set timing on
SQL>
SQL> -- CONNECT BY with REGEX
SQL> declare
  2     type t__num is table of number index by binary_integer;
  3     t_num t__num;
  4  begin
  5    for i in 1 .. 100000 loop
  6       select instr('SSSRNNSRSSR','R', 1, level)
  7         bulk collect into t_num
  8         from dual
  9      connect by level <= regexp_count('SSSRNNSRSSR', 'R')
 10              ;
 11     end loop;
 12  end;
 13  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:03.94
SQL>
SQL> -- CONNECT BY with filter
SQL> declare
  2     type t__num is table of number index by binary_integer;
  3     t_num t__num;
  4  begin
  5    for i in 1 .. 100000 loop
  6       select pos
  7         bulk collect into t_num
  8         from ( select substr('SSSRNNSRSSR', level, 1) as character
  9                     , level as pos
 10                  from dual t
 11               connect by level <= length('SSSRNNSRSSR') )
 12        where character = 'R'
 13              ;
 14     end loop;
 15  end;
 16  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:04.80
```

The pipelined table function is a fair bit slower, though it would be interesting to see how it performs over large strings with lots of matches.

```
SQL> -- PIPELINED TABLE FUNCTION
SQL> declare
  2     type t__num is table of number index by binary_integer;
  3     t_num t__num;
  4  begin
  5    for i in 1 .. 100000 loop
  6       select *
  7         bulk collect into t_num
  8         from table(string_indexes('SSSRNNSRSSR','R'))
  9              ;
 10     end loop;
 11  end;
 12  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:06.54
```

Comment: Nice solution and quite a bit shorter. I could be faster as well because of less recursion, but on the other hand, regex is slower than 'simple' string manipulations. Would like to se a benchmark.

Comment: It's not _that_ much slower @GolezTrol; I've done a simple benchmark and for this string and number of matches less recursion is better... as the string gets smaller it will make less (if any) difference.

Comment: So regex is faster, at least on a string of this size. Interesting. Thanks for the benchmark!

Comment: No problem. It's not just the size of the string but the number of matches that will make a different @GolezTrol, I would guess that benchmark's should be done on a "typical" string and use whichever one comes out fastest from that.

Comment: I am not supposed to use functions or procedures.But that query works!.How can i concatenate that result 3,8,11 into a single string 3$8$11?Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Using `LISTAGG()` would be the traditional approach @RajeenaSafeer, see http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/15010

Comment: when I am adding one more id field into it, 
        select mtr_id, instr(mtr_ctrl_flags,'R', 1, level) as str
                         from mer_trans_reject
        connect by level <= regexp_count(mtr_ctrl_flags, 'R');

Answer (score 9):

This is a solution:

```
select
  pos
from
  (select
    substr('SSSRNNSRSSR', level, 1) as character,
    level as pos
  from
    dual
  connect by
    level <= length(t.text))
where
  character = 'R'
```

`dual` is a built in table that just returns a single row. Very convenient!

`connect by` lets you build recursive queries. This is often used to generate lists from tree-like data (parent/child relations). It allows you to more or less repeat the query in front of it. And you've got special fields, like `level` that allows you to check how deeply the recursion went.

In this case, I use it to split the string to characters and return a row for each character. Using `level`, I can repeat the query and get a character until the end of the string is reached.

Then it is just a matter of returning the `pos` for all rows containing the character `'R'`

Answer (score 4):

To take up [a_horse_with_no_name's challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17906105/oracle-query-to-find-all-occurences-of-a-charcter-in-a-string#comment26156937_17906105) here is another answer with a [pipelined table function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10765/pipe_paral_tbl.htm#ADDCI2140).

A pipelined function returns an array, which you can query normally. I would expect that over strings with large numbers of matches this will perform better than the recursive query but as with everything test yourself first.

```
create type num_array as table of number
/


create function string_indexes (
    PSource_String in varchar2
  , PSearch_String in varchar2
    ) return num_array pipelined is

begin

   for i in 1 .. length(PSource_String) loop

      if substr(PSource_String, i, 1) = PSearch_String then
         pipe row(i);
      end if;

   end loop;

   return;

end;
/
```

Then in order to access it:

```
select *
  from table(string_indexes('SSSRNNSRSSR','R'))
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5f3ad/1)