# Concatinating entire column without any condition

Tags: oracle

I have a column whose values are `3,8,11`. I just want to concatenate with a separator.

The output should be `3-8-11`. I don't have any condition or group by parameter.

How can I write an oracle query for this?

Comment: Did [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17906105/oracle-query-to-find-all-occurences-of-a-charcter-in-a-string/17906575#comment26255569_17906575) and [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/15010) not give you enough information already? If you're not using 11.2 you need to state this in your question.

Comment: Hi Ben ,I have to add one more id field now,it's like         select mtr_id ,listagg(str,'#') within group(order by lvl) "flags" from(select mtr_id, instr(mtr_ctrl_flags,'R', 1, level) as str
              , level as lvl
           from mer_trans_reject
        connect by level <= regexp_count(mtr_ctrl_flags, 'R')group by mtr_id);