# Oracle instr position

Tags: oracle

I have 15 char string and need to loop through pulling the position of occurrence of the letter 'a'.  I was going to use a cursor to loop through the string, but wasn't sure how to save each positions occurrence.

Comment: Please include sample data along with desired output and any query you have tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle query to find all occurences of a charcter in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17906105/oracle-query-to-find-all-occurences-of-a-charcter-in-a-string)

Comment: Thanks Dr.Avalanche, that was useful.  Only issue I'm running into is that these instr functions have horrible performance on large tables.

Comment: What are you doing with the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this to break the string into each character and then filter on your desired value?

```
-- data setup to create a single value to test
WITH dat as (select 'ABCDEACDFA' val from DUAL)
--
SELECT lvl, strchr 
from (
    -- query to break the string into individual characters, returning a row for each
    SELECT level lvl, substr(dat.val,level,1) strchr
    FROM dat 
    CONNECT BY level <= length(val)
) WHERE strchr = 'A';

returns:
LVL    STRCHR
1      A
6      A
10     A
```

Comment: Thanks for posting.  Only issue is performance at this point.  I'm running on a huge table.

Comment: do you need all positions of all instances of your letter in all rows? can't help tune without exact requirements...

Comment: yes, all positions of 'a'.  So there could be one or more rows.

Comment: I don't envy you this then as there aren't really any fast ways string process a large table. one possibility would be a function-based index to provide a filter on rows that have at least one 'a' (index on regexp_count for example) so that you could "WITH applicaple_Data as (select where regexp_count > 1 )" so that you are only then doing the splitting on rows where at least one 'a' exists, but you still then need to do the parsing of the fields, and that will take time. Sometimes there are no magic bullets I'm afraid....

Comment: No worries. I appreciate the response.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different method using one less select and a regex.  I don't believe it will help your performance issue though.  Please try it and let us know:

```
SQL> with tbl(str) as (
     select 'Aabjggaklkjha' from dual
   )
   select level as position
   from tbl
   where upper(REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '.', 1, level)) = 'A'
   connect by level <= length(str);

  POSITION
----------
         1
         2
         7
        13

SQL>
```