# sql substr variable url extraction process

Tags: sql, oracle, parsing, substr

Context:
till now i uses to use regexp in sql to extract variable urls. I find it very slow and want to optimize it using substr and instr commands. That's important for me cause as i'm new in sql it serves me to be more familiar with such commands.

database:
my db is made by posts extracted from social platforms. text are called "titre". It contains variables url in different formats: www, http, https. I want to create a table or table view (i m not fixed) containing those url and the related id_post.

My work: 
I have noticed that url always ends with a blank space, sthg like: "toto want to share with you this www.example.com in his post"
here stands what i ve done so far:

```
---longueur de la chaîne de caractère depuis https
select LENGTH(substr(titre, INSTR(titre,'https:'))) from post_categorised_pages where id_post = '280853248721200_697941320345722';
---longueur de la chaîne de caractère depuis le blanc
select LENGTH(substr(titre, INSTR(titre,' ', 171))) from post_categorised_pages where id_post = '280853248721200_697941320345722';
--- différence pour obtenir la longueur de chaîne de caractères de l'url
select LENGTH(substr(titre, INSTR(titre,'https:'))) - LENGTH(substr(titre, INSTR(titre,' ', 171))) as longueur_url from post_categorised_pages where id_post = '280853248721200_697941320345722';
---url
select substr(titre, 171, 54)from post_categorised_pages where id_post = '280853248721200_697941320345722';
```

Question:
How can i automotasize that over the whole table "post_categorised_page"?
Can i introduce case when statements to take into account https or http of www. and how can i do that?

Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: and here stand the one liner version: ---one liner version
select substr(titre, INSTR(titre,'https:'), (LENGTH(substr(titre, INSTR(titre,'https:'))) - LENGTH(substr(titre, INSTR(titre,' ', (INSTR(titre,'https:')))))))from post_categorised_pages where id_post = '280853248721200_697941320345722';

Comment: Ok... second comment, this stuff works very fine when you encounter only 1 url into the string. How can i use connect by and level to loop over the string in order to retrieve all urls?

Comment: It is a little difficult to understand your request. can you post an example, please? It would be helpful to post your actual select statement, your example string and what you want to obtain.

Comment: ok mik. let's take this string: "Primeiramente  #ForaTemer. #ForaTodos!  Ninguém mais quer ser amigo do Eduardo Cunha." i want to extract all hashtags. If i use my solution (select substr(titre, INSTR(titre,'#'), (LENGTH(substr(titre, INSTR(titre,'#'))) - LENGTH(substr(titre, INSTR(titre,' ', (INSTR(titre,'#'))))))) from post_categorised_pages where id_post = '280853248721200_788642914608895';") i will only retrieve first #. In python we could loop over the string to catch all #. In SQL i don't know hos to do. I have heard about connect by level solutions but i can't figure how it works.

Comment: here is a beginning of solution in order to get all position of the specific string i am looking for:  with post as
 (select titre from post_categorised_pages where id_post= '521551221207650_653223808040390')
 select instr(titre,'#', 1, level)
   from post
connect by level <= regexp_count(titre, '#');

Comment: ok so, according the comment above, the request give me all position of a specific pattern in a given string. What i want to do now, is to get those positions and look for each one the position of the next blank space (' '). If i can do that, next step is to extract the string between each pattern1 position and each next blank space. Clear?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, instead of the "HTTP", HTTPS" or "WWW" string you would need to have the name of a column.
In this case, probably, it would be helpful to have a definition table where to define all possible sources. This tabel to have 2 columns (ID and source_name).

Then, in your `post_categorised_pages` table, to insert also the source of the message (the ID value).
Then, into the query, to join with this definition table by ID and, instead of

```
select substr(titre, INSTR(titre,'https:'), (LENGTH(substr(titre, INSTR(titre,'https:'))) - LENGTH(substr(titre, INSTR(titre,' ', (INSTR(titre,'https:')))))))from post_categorised_pages where id_post = '280853248721200_697941320345722';
```

to have

```
select substr(titre, INSTR(titre,"definition table".source_name), (LENGTH(substr(titre, INSTR(titre,"definition table".source_name))) - LENGTH(substr(titre, INSTR(titre,' ', (INSTR(titre,"definition table".source_name)))))))from post_categorised_pages where id_post = '280853248721200_697941320345722';
```

Comment: ok.... well i don't see waht you mean. i ll go to have a look to "definition table" it s a sql function?

Comment: No, it is not a function. It should be a table created by you, something like CREATE TABLE source(ID number, SOURCE_NAME varchar2(10)); INSERT INTO source (1, 'HTTP'); INSERT INTO source VALUES (2, 'HTTPS'); INSERT INTO source VALUES (3, 'WWW');

Comment: Or, you can have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17906105/oracle-query-to-find-all-occurrences-of-a-charcter-in-a-string

Comment: ahahahah oki yes i see! thanks for the tricks. I think i would do that but with only one sql command gathering in one table http, https and www source. I am now in big trouble to make my query loop over the string in order to get all html/# mentioned in this same string as i explained above.

Comment: i'm tryin the solution indicates in your link but it takes long time to get the count...

Comment: There is also a solution with a PL SQL function. You may create your own function to return the position of hashtag and the position of next space. Then, with this pair, you can get the string.

Comment: oh yes i ve shown that but i m not able to make any pl/sql programmation, or it will be my very first time ^^

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, here is the solution i have found (there is stil one mistake, see at end of post). 
I use two views to finally extract my strings. 
First view is create by a connect by request:

```
--- create intermediate table view with targeted pattern position
create or replace view Start_Position_Index as
with "post" as
(select id, text from "your_table" where id= 'xyz')
select id, instr(text,'#', 1, level) as position, text
from post
connect by level <= regexp_count(titre, '#');
```

then

```
--- create working table view with full references and blank position for each pattern match and string_lenght for each one
create or replace view _#_index as
select id, position as hashtag_pos, INSTR(text,' ', position) as blank_position, INSTR(text,' ', position) - position as string_length, text
from Start_Position_Index;
```

At the end you will be able to retrieve the hashtags (in that case) you were looking for in your string. 
Ok so the mistakes:
- if the pattern you are looking for is at the end of your string it will retrieve a null value cause there will be no blank space (as it is at end of the string).
- it is not well optimized cause here i am working with views and not tables. I think using tables will be faster.

But i m pretty sure there is lots of things to do in order to optimize this code... any idea? The challenge were how to extract specific pattern recursively among strings whithout using costy regex and without using pl/sql stuff. What do you think of that?

Answer (score 0):

How about using [Oracle Full Text](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/query.htm#g1016054) search?

This will index all the words from the column and will provide the hashtags or web addresses, as both are written in one word, without space in between.

Comment: Hello mikcutu, sorry to answer so lately. But yes, you've right, oracle text is very powerful, and I have tested it also. It works fine. I think I will put here some examples when I will be done with my analysis^^Thanks for reaction